# In Azure DevOps, how can I define a default template for a field of a work item?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using `Azure DevOps` and I want to provide a default template to a bug work item. I have added the existing Description field (with a multi-line rich editor).

I would like it to be configured by default like this when a new bug is opened:

[image: Default template]

I went to edit the `default value` of the description field, like this:

[image: Template]

The UI does not let me configure the multi-line field properly; I am unable to add new lines and use a bold font.

**Question**

How can I define a default template for a rich multi-line field?

Comment: For those wondering, here's instructions on how to create and change templates in Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-a-work-item-using-a-template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because is HTML field, you can add HTML tags when you define the default value, it will do the work:

[image]

Result:

[image]